# Spark Authentication error while connecting to MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication, apache-spark

I am trying to connect Spark (Java) application with MongoDB and facing authentication error.

However, I am able to connect to MongoDB with the same credentials using shell.

Below is the code which I am using to connect:

```
sparkContext.conf().set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://Host:port/DBname.CollectionName");
sparkContext.conf().set("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://username:password@Host:port/DBname.collectionName?authSource=DBName");
```

When giving username password I am getting `error code 18 authentication exception` and when trying without username/password I am getting `error code 13 authentication`. I only need to do read operations.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to connect and query on collection using MongoClient class.Below is the syntax:
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( new ServerAddress("host" , port),Arrays.asList(credentials));

My concern is how to connect this in spark using Java as I am still facing the Authorization error.

Any inputs are much appreciated.